# binding menu item to notebook tab in python

Tags: python-3.x, binding, tabs, tkinter, jupyter-notebook

I would like to bind a menu item to a notebook frame using a function(like gotofirst tab).
for instance a menu: file with 3 item such that if I click on the 3rd item in the menu file, the 3rd tab in the notebook should be selected or it should go to the 3rd tab and at the same time not see other tabs(hide them or disable them).

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

### defining functions ###

def GotoFirst():
    pass

def Gotosecond():
    pass

def Gotothird():
    pass

### Frame and notebook ###

root = Tk()
root.geometry('1000x700+1000+40')
root.resizable(FALSE,FALSE)
root.rowconfigure(0,weight=1)
root.columnconfigure(0,weight=1)
root.title("Test Fieldbook")




fieldbook = ttk.Notebook(root)
f1 = ttk.Frame(fieldbook);
f2 = ttk.Frame(fieldbook);
f3 = ttk.Frame(fieldbook);

fieldbook.add(f1, text="1st")
fieldbook.add(f2, text="2nd")
fieldbook.add(f3, text="3rd")

fieldbook.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=(N,W,S,E))

### Creating menu bar ###
menubar=Menu(root)



filemenu=Menu(menubar)
filemenu.add_command(label="Help Docs",command=GotoFirst)
filemenu.add_command(label="About ESB",command=Gotosecond)
filemenu.add_command(label="About ESB",command=Gotothird)

menubar.add_cascade(label="Help",menu=filemenu)
root.config(menu=menubar)

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for the hint, I manage to make it work.

```
fieldbook.tab(f1, state='normal')
fieldbook.select(f1)
fieldbook.hide(f3)
```

with .tab() I can change the state as I wish and with .hide() I can make a specific tab disappear momentarily and call it back anytime with .add()

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `select` method:

```
fieldbook.select(0)
```

and

```
fieldbook.select(f1)
```

do the same thing.

Comment: i have tried the select method, it does not select a disabled tab, i need to select and be able to change the state of any tab. Do you  know any method for that?